# Detect Form Feed Character

Tags: c#, file, text, special-characters, streamreader

I am using C# to read in a text file that has form feed characters in it.
I need to do something when I hit a line that starts with a form feed character.
How can I check for this?

Example:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
     string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
     //check currentLine to see if it begins with a form feed character
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currentLine = currentLine == null ? null : currentLine.TrimStart('\f');
```

Cannot do this:

```
string currentLine = reader.ReadLine().TrimStart('\f');
```

Because you may get a null ref exception.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do:

```
bool isFormFeed = (currentLine != null) && (currentLine.Length > 0) && (currentLine[0] == '\f');
```

where `'\f'` represents the Form Feed character.

By the way, it might be better to write your code like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    // ...
}
```

i.e. use a `using` to ensure the stream is closed.